# Did site activity grow noticeably as of summer 2012?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

I get the feeling that there's been a marked increase in new questions, particularly about the Higgs - no surprise there - but also on other topics, which may be associated with an influx of people coming here to ask Higgs questions and sticking around for at least some more while.

But then again, maybe I'm imagining things.

I'd therefore like to ask the people with access to that kind of statistics - is it real? if so, then maybe it's a good time to use this as a community to make a concerted effort at making sure as many newcomers as possible stick around.

Answer (score 6):

We're actually just seeing a bunch of Higgs questions in the last 12 hours or so, not really much earlier than that. In any case, up to yesterday, the site's activity has been nearly constant (perhaps very *slowly* growing) for quite a while. So no, the statistics don't reflect such a period of growth.

Comment: Good to know. I'll go get my head checked ;). Still, it might be useful to keep an eye on those stats for a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

Our pageviews are not significantly up suggesting that this is a transient phenomena associated with the CMS and Atlas announcements, but it could bring in more regular viewers. Only time will tell because right now we don't really have enough statistics.

Comment: Another useful metric is the "new users" one. Of course, not enough data yet :)